# There appears to be trouble with the npm registry (returned undefined). Retrying

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I'm trying to install dependencies in my project but when I run `yarn install` I get the following error

```
[2/5]   Resolving packages...
info There appears to be trouble with the npm registry (returned undefined). Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with the npm registry (returned undefined). Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with the npm registry (returned undefined). Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with the npm registry (returned undefined). Retrying...
⠁ axios@0.21.1/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.10/libexec/lib/cli.js:66965
            throw new (_errors || _load_errors()).ResponseError(_this3.reporter.lang('requestFailed', description), res.statusCode);
            ^

ResponseError: Request failed "502 Bad Gateway"
    at ResponseError.ExtendableBuiltin (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.10/libexec/lib/cli.js:696:66)
    at new ResponseError (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.10/libexec/lib/cli.js:802:124)
    at Request.params.callback [as _callback] (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.10/libexec/lib/cli.js:66965:19)
    at Request.self.callback (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.10/libexec/lib/cli.js:140749:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.10/libexec/lib/cli.js:141721:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.10/libexec/lib/cli.js:141643:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22) {
  responseCode: 502
}
```

I tried

1. to remove `yarn.lock` file and run `yarn install` again
2. to increase network timeout `yarn install --network-timeout 100000`

Still getting the same error

Comment: Are you under a proxy?

Answer (score 4):

this worked for me:

Delete any "*.lock" and rm node_modules. Or rm -rf node_modules/

Clean a flush all connections things like DNS, caches and so on.

Terminal commands:

```
 set http_proxy=

 set https_proxy=

 yarn config delete proxy

 npm config rm https-proxy

 npm config rm proxy
```

`npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org"` or `npm config set registry "https://registry.npmjs.org"`

Restart your terminal and Try.

Use : `yarn add mypckge --network-timeout 100000 or yarn --network-timeout 100000`

but first try just `yarn`

Restart your terminal and Try yarn again and/or with `--network-timeout`.

[link to MichelDiz answer](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5259#issuecomment-379769451)

Comment: It work after setting Yarn Registry and yarn add mypckge --network-timeout 100000.